# How do these eigenvalues group numbers into integer factorization forms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be the divisor matrix:

$$A(n,k): \text{If } n \bmod k=0 \text{ then } 1 \text{ else } 0$$

$$n=1,2,3,4,5,...,N$$
$$k=1,2,3,4,5,...,N$$

This is the infinite matrix starting:

[image: non swapped]

where black is one and white is zero.

Make the swap with the help of the variable $a$:

$$a = A(1, N)$$
$$A(1, N) = A(N, N)$$
$$A(N, N) = a$$

and call this new matrix, matrix $B$.

In  other words, let the value in the lower right corner of matrix $A$ change place with the value in the upper right corner of matrix $A$, and then call it matrix $B$.

An example of a such matrix $B$ is:

[image: corner swapped]

Then calculate the eigenvalues for this new matrix $B$ and look at the real part of the largest eigenvalue for each matrix. For $N=1,2,3,4,5,...$ this is a sequence starting:

{1., 1.61803, 1.61803, 2., 1.61803, 2.20557, 1.61803, 2.32472, 2., \
2.20557, 1.61803, 2.6717, 1.61803, 2.20557, 2.20557, 2.61803, \
1.61803, 2.6717, 1.61803, 2.6717, 2.20557, 2.20557, 1.61803, 3.08032, \
2., 2.20557, 2.32472, 2.6717, 1.61803, 2.93796, 1.61803, 2.89055, \
2.20557, 2.20557, 2.20557, 3.21878, 1.61803, 2.20557, 2.20557, \
3.08032, 1.61803, 2.93796}

For $N*N$ matrices with $N$ equal prime number, the real part of the largest eigenvalue appears to be the golden ratio. For other numbers of similar integer factorization the matrix sizes appear to be group as follows:

The largest eigenvalue is 1.000000000000000... for n equal to 1.

The largest eigenvalue is 1.618033988749894... for n found in [A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040), The prime numbers.

The largest eigenvalue is 2.000000000000000... for n found in [A001248](https://oeis.org/A001248), Squares of primes.

The largest eigenvalue is 2.205569430400590... for n found in [A006881](https://oeis.org/A006881), Squarefree semiprimes: Numbers that are the product of two distinct primes.

The largest eigenvalue is 2.324717957244746... for n found in [A030078](https://oeis.org/A030078), Cubes of primes.

The largest eigenvalue is 2.618033988749895... for n found in [A030514](https://oeis.org/A030514), 4th powers of primes.

The largest eigenvalue is 2.671699881657161... for n found in [A054753](https://oeis.org/A054753), Numbers which are the product of a prime and the square of a different prime.

And so on...

**Question**

> What is the general formula for how the real part of the largest
>   eigenvalues group the numbers into separate sequences that apparantly
>   have the same form of integer factorization in common?

The coefficients of the characteristic polynomials of matrix $B$ are recorded here: https://oeis.org/A275345.

Associated Mathematica code:

```
Clear[x, AA, nn, s]; Monitor[
 AA = Flatten[
   Table[A = 
     Table[Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1, 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]; 
    MatrixForm[A]; a = A[[1, nn]]; A[[1, nn]] = A[[nn, nn]]; 
    A[[nn, nn]] = a; Max[Re[N[Eigenvalues[A]]]], {nn, 1, 42}]], nn]
```

Answer (score 0):

For $N$ equal to a prime number the contributing elements appear to be:

```
nn = 7;
A = Table[
   Table[If[And[n == nn, k == nn], 0, 
     If[n == k, 1, 
      If[Or[And[n == 1, k == nn], And[n == nn, k == 1]], 1, 0]]], {k, 
     1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[A]
```

This a matrix $A$ starting:

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$$

Looking at the characteristic polynomial:

```
Factor[CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x]]
```

we see that it has the form:

$$-(x-1)^5 \left(x^2-x-1\right)$$

Solving:

```
Reduce[(-1 - x + x^2) == 0, x]
```

$$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\lor x=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)$$

of which the largest eigenvalue is the Golden ratio:
1.61803...